# Checking if a macro is called in another macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of macros in my excel. I don't know whether they are used in that workbook. I don't know whether it is called as a procedure inside other macros.

Is there any way to find out whether the macro is used inside another macros or used in different sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Write the name of the "Macro" and select search in Current Project. Then start counting how many times it will show up.

Another way is to write `debug.print "I am used"` after the `Sub` line of the "Macro". Then count how many times has it popped up on the immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

- put “Option Explicit” at the beginning of every module
- comment out your “Macro
- start debug

  And it’ll point you to any occurrence of “Macro” call